# In Jenkins, is there a way to bring the tasks from "Add Post Build Action" to "Add Build step"?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, is there a way to bring the tasks from "Add Post Build Action" to "Add Build step"?

For e.g. In my particular scenario I want "Publish MSTEST test result report" task from "Add Post Build Action" to "Add Build Step", So as to execute some other tasks once this is completed.

I am using Freestyle project with Jenkins 2.71.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never came across a direct way to bring tasks for "Add Post Build Action" to "Add Build Step."

Again, if I am reading your question right then you want to execute other tasks after publishing the MSTest report.

If you can execute those tasks using shell scripts, then the Hudson Post Build Task plugin is what you need.

You can use [Hudson Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin to execute other tasks as shell scripts after a Post-build action.

[image]

If you cannot execute your task using just Shell script then you can try [Any Build Step Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin#AnyBuildStepPlugin-features) to achieve your requirement.

This plugin will help you to execute certain tasks based on conditions. In your case, you have `Publish MSTest Result` in the Post-build action and want to execute few tasks after this step.

Since this step is in Post-build section, execution of this step decides the state of your job. So, what you can do is on the successful execution of your Post-build action you can call other tasks that you want to execute.

Once you install this plugin you will get `Conditional step` in the `Build` section. if you need to execute a single task after the `Post-build action` choose single or if you have multiple tasks then choose multiple.

[image]

Then choose `Current build status` as the run condition. And select the Worst and Best Status both as `Success`. This is where you tell the job that only execute my conditional tasks only if the build is successful.

[image]

Now as you can see in the above image we have a section called `Steps to run if condition is met.` Now under that, you can find build tasks that you want to execute after your build is successful. Choose the tasks you want to execute after your build is successful.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining in such detail. I used "Hudson Post Build Task" to run a batch script which worked fine and planning to use "conditional step" to further deploy the artifacts as a 'last' post build action. Thanks once again.

Comment: @KrishanKant I am glad that helped :)